# PDFsharp Documentation

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

Is it possible to find good documentation for the PDFsharp library?

I searched on Google but I didn't find any reference documentation.

I don't know how `XGraphics.RotateAtTransform` and `XGraphics.TranslateTransform` work.

Comment: Here, I searched google for you http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/XForms-sample.ashx?HL=rotate

Comment: @AnotherUser There they used it. But what it does it's not explained!

Comment: Play around with it then, figure out what it does. Give it different inputs, see what it outputs.

Answer (score 12):

The PDFsharp documentation is included in the source code.

Help files created 2009 from the source code can be found here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/files/pdfsharp/PDFsharp%201.31/

The XGraphics class implements the same functions as the Graphics class from GDI+.

So for further information about the two methods given in the question, search information about `Graphics.RotateAtTransform` and `Graphics.TranslateTransform` from System.Drawing.

Comment: This link is now dead.

Comment: @cyclingLinguist Fixed the link, but help files are from 2009. But there were only minor API changes.

Answer (score 8):

API documentation for PdfSharp and MigraDoc (GDI+ version) is available at http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Projects/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI

Enter "xgraphics" into the search box to find information about the `XGraphics` class.

Comment: The link is now dead.

Comment: This appears to be the new home for PdfSharp, specifically for the XGraphics class [link](https://hiraokahypertools.github.io/PDFsharp/pdfsharp-wpf/html/class_pdf_sharp_1_1_drawing_1_1_x_graphics.html)