# Where is the PDFsharp documentation?

Tags: pdfsharp

All, I was trying to learn to use PDFsharp (MigraDoc) to generate PDF. So I tried to find an API document in the official website of PDFsharp to get reference when I have trouble with reading the sample code of PDFsharp. Like `Paragraph.AddTab` (What does it mean?).
Here it is http://www.pdfsharp.net/ I looking for.

But I am sorry for failing to find this document.

Could someone please show me the link of document? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone has asked the same question before, please see:[PDFsharp Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914962/pdfsharp-documentation)."documentation" is the key word to find a reference. [This](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI/MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel/FormattedText/M/AddTab) works.